# Query on ID using Google App Engine models

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an entity in my datastore:

```
In [38]: i1
Out[38]: <my_app.models.Infospot at 0x4255a90>

In [39]: i1.key().id()
Out[39]: 162L
```

But I can't query based on its ID:

```
In [41]: Infospot.get_by_id(162L) is None
Out[41]: True

In [45]: Infospot.get(Key.from_path('Infospot', 162L)) is None
Out[45]: True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the first piece of code you're doing model based operations which can return results even if the entity is not actually stored in the data store. In the second piece of code, you're basically running queries which check the data store for saved entries. And it's returning None. So no entries with this type and ID is found in the data store. Could it be that you're forgetting to put the object before querying? It

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems likely that your `Infospot` entity is a child entity. An entity is uniquely identified by its kind, ID, and all its parents, so attempting to fetch it as a root entity will not work.

You can verify if this is the case by printing out the value of `i1.key()`; if it looks something like `datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Something', 123L, 'Infospot', 162L)`, that indicates the entity is a child of an entity of kind `Something`.

Comment: Bingo! `i1.key()` => `datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Something', 126001L, u'SomethingElse', 113L, u'Infospot', 162L, _app=u's~foo-bar')`